# Pass object to underscore.js template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js-templating

I'm trying to pass an object to an underscore.js (1.8.3) template and use it in the template script. Simple example from the console:

```
> t = _.template("<% console.log(data) %>", {data: 42})
> t()

Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

What is the correct way to pass an object to a template script for use inside?

Note: I know for substituting simple values, just do this:

```
t = _.template("<%= data %>")
t({data:42})
<- "42"
```

But I really need to pass and use objects in a more complicated script.

**Update**

This works:

```
> t = _.template("<% console.log(data) %>")
> t({data: [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

I swear I'm not crazy (well not much)... I was looking at [this really good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk) on backbone.js where he passes the object like `template("...", object)`.  Perhaps this is the way they did it in an older version of underscore.js (version 1.4.2 in the video)?

Comment: what do you mean by "a more complicated script"??

Comment: `<% _.each(data, function(datum) { %>` ... but let's not get lost in the weeds :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version [1.7.0](http://underscorejs.org/#1.7.0) Underscore templates no longer accept an initial data object. `_.template` always returns a function now.

Answer (score 0):

[underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template) use Mustache.js to render, so you should use it's "Logic-less" syntax instead of executing JS code.

According to their [docs example](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#non-empty-lists), you should be able to iterate without using the code you provided in the comments section: `<% _.each(data, function(datum) { %>`, but use the template instead

```
<%
{{#datum}}
<b>{{datumvalue}}</b>
{{/datum}}
%>
```

EDIT: That't true (thanks for pointing it out [Uzi Kilon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330092/uzi-kilon)), underscore does not use mustache, after a second look into the docs, it says you can use "Mustache.js-style" by adding the following settings before compiling:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Which should still be considered to avoid a lot of JS in the template and keep the project sanity

Comment: I tried to work something up in the console and I'm getting an Unexpected token ILLEGAL (ALL CAPS!).  Can you add to your answer to show us how it's done?

Comment: This is incorrect. underscore templates do NOT use mustache.